# How to run timer in the background when Activity finishes and then continue again

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, countdowntimer

How to save timer in sharedpreferences and then fetch again when activity restarts
I have to set a timer of 5 mins and it should running in the background and when activity restart it should continue and it should not be restart again from 5 mins remaining

```
new CountDownTimer(300000,1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timer.setText("Time Left: "+String.format("%d : %d min(s)",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }.start();
```

And what will be variable in sharedpreferences class?

```
public static final long OrderTimeLeft = 300000;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

**Keep timer running in background**

This result can be achieved pretty easily by a simple trick. You just need to store the startTime of your timer.

```
long startTime; // Global variable

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // save the time in preference
new CountDownTimer(300000,1000){
//.......
}
```

before resuming

```
// retrieve the startTime from preference
// now calculate the remaining time 
long remainingTime = 300000 - System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
// start your counter from here
```

**Old answer**

you need to store the remainingTime from timer.

```
long remainingTime; // Global variable

new CountDownTimer(300000,1000){
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        remainingTime = 300000 - millisUntilFinished;
//.......
}
```

`onPause()` store this value in sharedPref and `onResume()` retrieve the value and initiate your timer with that value

Comment: No, i want to run timer in the background and continue it. It should not restart

Comment: the updated answer should be done in onResume() and onPause() methods?